# Insert specific rows from one table in database into another with different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm encountering problems moving data from one table to another. I have two tables, one stores all users who are members of a website, however there are VIP members that get random points when they sign up, regular members do not.

```
+-----------+
|   Users   |
+-----------+
| User_id   |
| Usertype  |
| Firstname |
| Lastname  |
| Email     |
| Username  |
| Password  |
+-----------+

+-------------+
| VIP_Members |
+-------------+
| User_id     |
| Username    |
| Points      |
+-------------+
```

I want to select all VIP members (determined by Usertype) and move them into **VIP Members** table:

```
INSERT INTO Vip_Members (Points)
VALUES (ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 11)
SELECT User_id, Username
FROM Users
WHERE Usertype = 'vip';
```

Comment: What error are you running into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you want to use here is `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.  The `VALUES` keyword is mainly used when you want to insert literal constants in an `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO Vip_Members (User_id, Username, Points)
SELECT User_id, Username, ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 11
FROM Users
WHERE Usertype = 'vip';
```

As a side note, I don't know why you want to move users from the `Users` table to a separate table.  I think it's fine to have a type column which determines whether or not a user be a VIP.

Comment: this is just a snippet of an exercise problem for school lol, I completely agree with your side note.